# CTGAN for tabular data

Tags: tabular, generative-adversarial-network

I am using CTGAN for generating more data from my original data, but when I fit the data I receive a warning :

**code**

```
real_data = pd.read_csv('/content/data_gan.csv')

    discrete_columns = [
        'gender','age_group'
    ]
     
    ctgan = CTGANSynthesizer(epochs=50)
    ctgan.fit(real_data, discrete_columns)
    
    synthetic_data = ctgan.sample(1000)
    print(synthetic_data.head(10))
```

**warning**

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/mixture/_base.py:146: ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters (9) found smaller than n_clusters (10). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
  .fit(X)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/mixture/_base.py:282: ConvergenceWarning: Initialization 1 did not converge. Try different init parameters, or increase max_iter, tol or check for degenerate data.
  ConvergenceWarning,
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/mixture/_base.py:282: ConvergenceWarning: Initialization 1 did not converge. Try different init parameters, or increase max_iter, tol or check for degenerate data.
  ConvergenceWarning,
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/mixture/_base.py:282: ConvergenceWarning: Initialization 1 did not converge. Try different init parameters, or increase max_iter, tol or check for degenerate data.
  ConvergenceWarning,
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ctgan/data_transformer.py:111: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  data[column_name] = data[column_name].to_numpy().flatten()
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ctgan/data_transformer.py:111: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Also, when I call the visual_evaluation method to compare the actual data and the generated data(samples) I always receive this error:

**Code**

```
table_evaluator = TableEvaluator(real_data, synthetic_data)
table_evaluator.visual_evaluation()
```

**Erorr**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-d6231583be25> in <module>()
      4 table_evaluator =  TableEvaluator(data, samples, cat_cols= categorical_features)
      5 
----> 6 table_evaluator.visual_evaluation()

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _validate_can_reindex(self, indexer)
   3783         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3784         if not self._index_as_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3785             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3786 
   3787     def reindex(

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

[image]

How can I fix these issues?

Note: my data columns are decimal and categorical.

Comment: Hey, I just got the same warning in a similar context (also synthetic data generation)...
Have you been able to resolve the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason below mentioned code is working without any error

```
from table_evaluator import load_data, TableEvaluator
cat_cols = ['energy_median','energy_mean']
print(len(real), len(fake))
table_evaluator =  TableEvaluator(real, fake)
table_evaluator.visual_evaluation()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?